# System.InvalidOperationException loading mySQL information

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I was toying around with the Azure Data Factory using the [Sakila Dataset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/). I set up a Maria DB (5.5.64) on a private centos7.7-vm. I also ran into the same issue when I was using MySQL 8 instead of MariaDB.

I run a parameterized load pipeline in Azure Data Factory. I repeatedly get this error inside a foreach loop in the Azure Data Factory. I get the error every time with a different source table.

Error from Azure Data Factory:

```
{     
   “errorCode”: “2100”,
   “message”: “’Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.,Source=mscorlib,’”,
   “failureType”: “UserError”,
   “target”: “GET MAX MySQL”, 
   “details”: [] 
}
```

Parameterized query running in the lookup activity:

```
SELECT MAX(@{item().WatermarkColumn}) as maxd FROM @{item().SRC_tab}
```

becomes

```
SELECT MAX(last_update) as maxd FROM sakila.actor
```

Please note that the error appeared the last time in the staff and the category table, I was using the MariaDB connector. After I switched to the MySQL connector, the error disappeared. However in the past when I used the MySQL connector, and switched to the MariaDB connector the error also persisted.

Have any of you experienced a similar behaviour? If yes, what were your workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Apologizes , but we need more clarity here . As I understand is this issue still with and MariaDB connection and MySQL or only with MySQL ?

Just to let you know ADF team regularly deploys changes and it may happen that the issues which you experienced and is not repro-able at this time , a fix may have been deployed for that .

Comment: As of one week ago it was still an issue. Will run another test today to answer your question

Comment: Have the issue with MySQL connector as well